# AJAX submit form with jQuery in <body>

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

The body on my page is generated dynamically so I have to put the jQuery in the body:

```
<div>

<form action="insertMessage.php" method="post" name="contactForm" id="contactForm">
    Name:<br />
    <input type="text" id="inputName" name="inputName" value=""><br />
    Email:<br />
    <input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" value=""><br />
    Phone:<br />
    <input type="text" id="inputPhone" name="inputPhone" value=""><br />
    Comment:<br />
    <textarea name="inputComment" form="contactForm"> </textarea><br/>
    <input class="button color_pearl size_small" type="submit" id="inputSubmit" value="SEND">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //callback handler for form submit
        $("#contactForm").submit(function(e)
        {
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    alert(data);     
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });
    });
</script>

    </div>
```

From looking at another forum on the net I found that this should work, but the page behaves as if the jQuery was not present. The form is just POSTed normally, ignoring my AJAX attempt.

All other jQuery, including AJAX Form Submission, works fine. This is the only thing that doesn't work on the page and I suspect it's because it's in the body. jQuery and the rest is loaded at the top of the page.

[You can see page here.](http://rlcoaching.com/index.php?page=contact)

Comment: Put e.preventDefault() right after submit.function and at the end write return false;

Comment: So what's problem? It's interesting to me also.

Comment: Q: If you display your page in Chrome with the F12 debug tools open, do you get any errors?

Comment: Must check my variant. I think preventing before caling ajax should resolve the.problem.

Comment: Must.check.how.fast the.browser."understand" to.prevent.the.event.

Comment: I always preventdefault event before doing something.

Comment: Someone plz check the solution in answer.to prove that I'm wrong.) I'm not behind the PC)

Comment: When you say "body on my page is generated dynamically" do you mean the form too? If so, a `delegated event handler` is required so `Sakai`'s answer would be correct.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie *"The browser waits for the callback function to exit"* What?!?!?!

Comment: Moving the `e.preventDefault()` to the top WILL have good effects with the code. it won't stop the problem from happening, but it will at least stop the page from posting so that the error can be easily seen in the console

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie why are You so agressive? We.are learning from mistakes. Maybe You're God in JS. It's your victory. Plz be calm.)))

Comment: having the contents generated dynamically does NOT mean you have to have your javascript in the body...

Comment: Wrong. If an error occurs before e.preventDefault() happens, the page will post as if it has no submit event stopping it. Moving it to the top prevents it before any errors can occur.

Comment: @nzifnab I actually tried by putting the code in the header first. It didn't work. I figured it was because the form does not exist on original page load but appears when user clicks somewhere. So tried to put it in body

Comment: @Juicy Putting it in the body won't fix that. it'l need to be in the click event, or it will need to be a delegated event.

Comment: Kevin B: *sigh* Hence my original check the console comment :)

Comment: @Juicy plz provide full.code - the whole of html page.

Comment: Right, but to someone who is relatively new to debugging, they won't know how to stop the page reload to see an error in the console.

Comment: @num8er Full html is way too big for here. I've provided a link to my site where you can see it though! :)

Comment: @Kevin B: Ok, I am quite willing to say that placing `preventDefault()` first *is a good idea* (I do myself), if you will agree that is impossible for it to be *the cause of the actual problem, as num8er insists*. It may just be masking the problem (if the code is crashing). Actual solution: As I said earlier it needed a delegated event :)

Comment: @ Everyone Thanks for the help. Sakai's answer worked like a charm. Code is now in header, just had to specify it Sakai's way.

Comment: @Juicy: Please use nzifnab's version in practice (`document` and not `'`body'` as the fallback element for delegated events). There are weird side-effects on using `body` with some events :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this before creating the body:

```
$(document).on('submit','#contactForm', function(){ .... });
```

This works for me all the time, because using the on it doesn't matter if you destroy and create the new element it's binded on the body and it searchs for the form id or any selector you put in the second string of the "on".

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! So this is how I declare jQuery for something that doesn't exist on page load!

Comment: Or for something that you change all the time, like a <tr> or <a> on a ajax filtered table.

Comment: **Please note**: Do not use `body` with delegated events. Use the closest static element above the changing elements, or `document` if there isn't one handy. `body` has weird side effects with some events. :)

Comment: If you change this to `$(document)` instead of `$('body')` I will upvote as it was the earliest correct answer, but `'body'` *can* cause problems so I can't condone its common use in delegated events :)

Answer (score 2):

Putting the JS in the body won't fix your problem. If the content is being loaded after initial page load you need to use delegated events.  Have you tried changing your event handler to

```
$(document).on("submit", "#contactForm", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Oh look, I submitted!");
  // Other code here
}
```

Read more about the `on` function and delegated events in the [jquery documentation (click here)](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: +1: This answer is better as you should avoid `body` in delegated events (you get weird side effects on some events).

Answer (score 0):

here is part of code that I've changed. try this and give feedback:

```
    $(function(){
        $('body').on('submit','#contactForm', function(event){ 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var postData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : 'insertMessage.php',
                type: "post",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    alert(data);     
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: The return false is unnecessary, but otherwise the delegation is correct. However, you're about 25 minutes late.